# How to update multiple objects in array in a single mongodb document using mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongoose

I know that this can be a repeat question but none of the existing answers solved my problem.

I have a `friendsSchema` like below:

```
const friendsSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Player'
    },
    friends: [{
        friendId: {
            type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Player'
        },
        isFromFacebook: {
            type: Boolean,
            default: false
        },
        thisFriendReceivedGiftTimeStamp: {
            type: Date,
            default: null
        },
        thisFriendSentGiftTimeStamp: {
            type: Date,
            default: null
        }
    }]
}, {
    timestamps: true
});
```

The client is sending me an array of `friendsIds`.

So, I want to find all objects in `friends` array which matches all `friendsIds` and update their `thisFriendReceivedGiftTimeStamp` to `Date.now()`.

Consider the client is sending 100s of ids in `friendsIds` array, what will be the most efficient way to achieve the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
db.collection.update({IF YOU WANT TO ADD QUERY ACCORDING TO OWNER FIELD PLEASE ADD HERE},
{
  "$set": {
    "friends.$[x].thisFriendReceivedGiftTimeStamp": new Date()
  }
},
{
  "arrayFilters": [
    {
      "x.friendId": {
        $in: [
          1,
          3,
          5
        ]
      }
    }
  ],
  "multi": true
})
```

[arrayFilters](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-filtered/) should work great here. But I am not 100% sure about efficiency

Here is a working [mongoplayground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RoSnW_iNMaA)